# Bluemix: Does Delivery Pipeline support roll back of deployment

Tags: ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops, active-deploy, delivery-pipeline

I am trying to understand the key differences of the deployment capabilities of `Delivery Pipeline` versus `Active Deploy`.

From different documentations, I could understand that `Active Deploy` can deploy with zero downtime and support rollback.

I am curious to know the deployment capabilities of `Delivery Pipeline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delivery pipeline is capable of doing zero downtime deployments.  There is an article [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-rollingpipeline/) that describes how to do it.  It is a little out dated, but it mostly holds.

As for doing rollbacks, the pipeline probably does not handle them as well as active deploy would.  You can redeploy an older build over a newer one to do the rollback, but that is about it.

There is currently work be done to add some of the active deploy features to the delivery pipeline.